# Auto-space within input field

Tags: html, forms, input, spacing, restrict

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to fetch street/city details from a DB using a zipcode. Dutch zipcodes use a "1111 AA" format, I would like to have this entered in a single input field while automatically adding the space in between the numbers and letters if the user doesn't enter the space himself.

I've been googling this quite a bit and all I have been able to find so far were ways of restricting the user input to numeric characters.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting to this pre or post submission? Javascript can be used to perform this task pre-submission. Post-submission you can use whatever backend language you're using to parse the submitted value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need JavaScript to do that. In this case, jQuery can actually help you a lot. Here's a **[neat plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)** to handle what you want:

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool for such operations in HTML. You could code the functionality in JavaScript, using a keypress event handled that checks whether four consecutive digits have been entered and appends a space in the positive case. This gets more difficult if you consider what should happen if the user presses the delete key to remove characters. You would also have the problem that users may type “1111 AA” pressing the space bar, and what should happen then?

So it’s of questionable usefulness. It’s better to just accept the zip code with and without a space.

Comment: the event is handled by an AJAX call, I wouldn't know how to accept the zipcode in both cases.